# Downloading MCX data using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to download data on margin requirements from the MCX website using R
However, I am unable to recognise the appropriate url to use in order to download this data.

The [link is here](https://www.mcxindia.com/market-operations/clearing-settlement/daily-margin)

files for different dates have seemingly different urls

for instance:

- > DailyMargin_20170919223427.csv
- > DailyMargin_20170919223104.csv
- > DailyMargin_20170919223039.csv

They seem to be of the form

> DailyMargin_2017091922****.csv

(20170919 is the date on which I'm trying to download the data)

My code has the line:

```
myURL = paste("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-operations/clearing-settlement/daily-margin", "DailyMargin_2017091922","****", ".csv", sep = "")
```

the ****** part seems to be random.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the remaining **** appears to be a timestamp when the data are created by the webpage using javascript. You will probably not be able to directly download data as it will not exist until it is created. That said, you might be able to utilize a package like rvest to do the scrapping for you.

https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/

Comment: My bad. I've changed the link. 
https://www.mcxindia.com/market-operations/clearing-settlement/daily-margin